# Adobe Air for cross-platform iOS and Android development

Tags: android, ios, air

I saw this sometime ago and wanted to check if anyone with experience doing cross-platform Application using Adobe AIR. I have seen their LVVM compiler with AOT and Android runtime.

Say I need to create the same application for iOS and Android, is this recommended? Are they any limiation that I don't aware yet? Can they access to respective's native API? Are things like Animation h/w accelerated? Any performance penalty?

Answer (score 0):

It really depend on the application that you want to build. Adobe Air is more focus on game development, but not saying it can't be used for application usage. Plus there are some cool native plug-in which can boost up your application. I suggest to understand your project requirement and have a checklist against Adobe air, then decide to implement or not.

Have a read the following review by Cnet about this product.
http://download.cnet.com/Adobe-AIR/3000-2383_4-10652806.html

Answer (score -1):

You can create IOS and android application Using PhoneGap.

Comment: we need native performance.. phonegap is out. we looked at that before. i am wondering if AIR can give me that performance?

Comment: phoneGap is likely a container of HTML. Javascript is not going to give a good performance.